# execvp ls: cannot access ' ': No such file or directory

Tags: c, fork, exec, ls

When I try to execute a command like ls without arguments with execvp, I get the error: ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory.

I dont know why, cause it seems like he is searching for a parameter ''.

The code works like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char command[250] = "ls";              
    argvs[0] = command;
    argvs[1] = NULL;
    if (execvp( argvs[0], argvs) == -1 )
       perror("exec failed");

    return 0;
 }
```

Do I have to give as minimum one argument in execvp ? and set this to NULL or some other nullterminations?

Comment: What is `argvs` ?

Comment: argvs is the char array for the execvp. I set there the command and NULL at the end.

Comment: `argvs is the char array for the execvp` that does not work you need `array of pointers` Please provide [mcve]

Comment: The code as shown will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

If `argvs` is declared as below

```
char *argvs[2]; /* array of pointer */
```

then the below code should work on your machine

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        char command[250] = "ls";
        char *argvs[2];
        argvs[0] = command;
        argvs[1] = NULL;
        if (execvp( argvs[0], argvs) == -1 )
                perror("exec failed");

        return 0;
}
```

> *Do I have to give as minimum one argument in execvp?*

From the manual page of `execvp`

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]); /*its having fixed no of argument */
```

that means you have to provide exactly two argument to `execvp()`.

Comment: "*`char *argvs[3];`*": Why `3`, as `2` would do?

Comment: yes @alk true. I thought Op may give like `ls -l` etc.